# Reading data from multiple sensors from Arduino with ESP8266

Tags: arduino-mega, esp8266

I am trying to do a project where I need to get data from multiple sensors simultaneously. I am planning to use a Arduino to get the readings from the sensors. I am thinking to control the Arduino using ESP8266 as I would finally like to have internet capabilities for my project. I have worked with Arduino before but this is my first time with ESP8266 and I don't know much about. What I would like to know is if its feasible? I read that I need to use SoftwareSerial library to achieve this. Am I correct? I have tried to google for similar examples but most of the results direct to using a single pin on the Arduino controlled by ESP8266 and the Blynk app. Apart from that I could not find much information. I would be very much grateful if you could point out some similar projects or examples. Thanks a lot for your time in advance.

Comment: You want to use the esp8266 as the main MCU or only as network adapter? I recommend the second option with Mega. Mega has 4 Serials so don't use SoftwareSerial. I you put AT firmware 1.7 in the esp8266, you can use my WiFiEspAT library

Comment: Hi Juraj. I intend to use Mega as the main MCU and esp8266 as the network adapter. I will look into the WiFiEspAT library as you suggested. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: What are those sensors? Why don't you just use the esp without the arduino?

Comment: i always do it backwards, if for no other reason than OTA is faster for dev cycles and the ESP is WAY faster/stronger than the mega, making it the better "brain"

Comment: Sim, I need to use multiple load cells and a solenoid lock. So I am planning to use mega as it gives me more I/O pins.